# On change of bootstrap drop-down send post data to controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have drop-down in my views,
Now i want to send POST data to my controller for the item i select from `<li></li>` tag.

So basically what i want is when i select anything from the drop-down i want to trigger java-script to send the selected item in **POST** to my **controller**

Below is my dropdown. How do i put a fomr in here and send the data to controller?

```
 <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Your Sites <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li  onchange="this.form.submit()"><a href="#"><?php

    foreach($sites as $site)
    {

    echo "<li>".$site->site_key."</li>";
    }?></a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: You are mistaken when you choose that component. Bootstrap Dropdown is only that, a dropdown  that shows and hides a list. You must to use a plugin that converts a `<select>` element, like [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)  or [select2](https://select2.github.io/) for example

Answer (score 1):

Your Sites

```
foreach($sites as $site)
{

echo "<li>".$site->site_key."</li>";
}?></a></li>

  </ul>
</li>
<script>
   $("#form_name").validate({
      rules: {          
        dropdown: {  
            remote: "controller_name"
        },
 </script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: u can use remote jquery validator to do it

Comment: where should i define my form?

Comment: i have some question, where will me my form ? also will it always send post data?

Comment: when i write form tag in <li> my nav bar looks bad

Comment: in codeigniter form it always send ur data by post method whether  u define it or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104637/discussion-between-sukhwinder-sodhi-and-rajan).

Answer (score 1):

```
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Your Sites 
   <span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul>
   <?php
      if (count($resultset) > 0) {
        foreach ($resultset as $key => $val) { ?>
     <li >
   <a href="<?php base_url() ?>controller/function_name/?name=<?php echo $val['name'] ?>">                             
    <?php echo $val['name'];}}?>
   </a></li>

  </ul>
```

//controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
  class demo extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('factory_model');

}
public function index(){
    $data["master_title"] = $this->config->item('sitename')." | Factory";
    $data['sort'] = $this->input->post("sort"); 


    $data['resultset'] = $this->factory_model->factory();

    $data["item"] = "Driver";

    $data["master_body"]="demo";  
    $this->load->theme('layout',$data);


       }

       public function demo_name()
       {
           $name = $_GET['name'];
           echo $name;
           die;
       }

 }
```

// model

```
<?php 

class factory_model extends CI_Model { 
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function factory(){
$this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("factory");

    $query = $this->db->get();
    //echo $this->db->last_query();die;
    $resultset = $query->result_array();
    //debug($resultset);
    return $resultset;
}
}
```

Comment: I did not understand this ?? What is searchdata here?

Comment: i am confused how to use this :(

Comment: i used it for getting result in an array i used that for pagination but u dnt need that

Comment: i dont have anything in my controller, i just have a model that fetches the data and i show it in my view in dropdown,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104702/discussion-between-rajan-and-sukhwinder-sodhi).